# Convert Serial Number From and To to single row

Tags: oracle

We need a solution to convert in Oracle SQL.

We have serial numbers input from a third party system and it is Stored in the following format.

[image]

We want the values to be Displayed in the following format in Reports.

[image]

Comment: Use a row generator. There are examples in the linked duplicates or [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oaVrECT5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a *row generator*.

One option is, with sample data:

```
SQL> with ship (shipment_no, item_number, quantity, fm_serial_number, to_serial_number) as
  2    (select 26, 'A', 18, 288, 305 from dual union all
  3     select 27, 'B', 18, 144, 161 from dual
  4    )
```

Query:

```
  5  select shipment_no, item_number, 1 quantity,
  6    fm_serial_number + column_value - 1 as serial_number
  7  from ship cross join
  8    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                        connect by level <= to_serial_number - fm_serial_number + 1
 10                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 11  order by shipment_no, serial_number;
```

Result:

```
SHIPMENT_NO ITEM_NUMBER    QUANTITY SERIAL_NUMBER
----------- ------------ ---------- -------------
         26 A                     1           288
         26 A                     1           289
         26 A                     1           290
         26 A                     1           291
         26 A                     1           292
         26 A                     1           293
         26 A                     1           294
         26 A                     1           295
         26 A                     1           296
         26 A                     1           297
         26 A                     1           298
         26 A                     1           299
         26 A                     1           300
         26 A                     1           301
         26 A                     1           302
         26 A                     1           303
         26 A                     1           304
         26 A                     1           305
         27 B                     1           144
         27 B                     1           145
         27 B                     1           146
         27 B                     1           147
         27 B                     1           148
         27 B                     1           149
         27 B                     1           150
         27 B                     1           151
         27 B                     1           152
         27 B                     1           153
         27 B                     1           154
         27 B                     1           155
         27 B                     1           156
         27 B                     1           157
         27 B                     1           158
         27 B                     1           159
         27 B                     1           160
         27 B                     1           161

36 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

Have a look at more options on [OraFAQ - Row generator techniques](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques).

Comment: Do you know how to do row generator for Alpha numeric case?

Comment: Possibly, but - that's a new problem. If this question has been answered (I'd say it is), mark it and open a new question for whatever you're interested in.